# how to obtain data inside a CDATA section using Xpath from a XML

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

how to obtain data inside a CDATA section using Xpath from a XML.
I have embedded a html code inside a CDATA section within an XML like shown below

```
<xml>
  <node1>
    <![CDATA[ <div id= "div1">Hi howdy</div> ]]>
  </node1>
</xml>
```

How can I access it directly from Xpath.
I can get the text of node1
by using `.//node1/text()`

What is the correct Xpath for getting the contents inside the CDATA section as a html document.

Comment: Hi Quentin, I am not trying to create a html element dynamically.I want to pass a html to front end in CDATA section of an XML.Now i want to select the content inside the CDATA using XPath. I am looking for the XPath.

Comment: `//node1/text()` does select what you want. What do you mean you want it as a HTML *document*, it is just a page fragment.

Comment: i didn't post the entire content here. this is an example.I want to again parse it. If i can make it into a document then i can parse it.

Comment: Anyway, `text()` does return the content of the CDATA section, so what is the problem?